# SP 2010, Infopath form, not returning queries after FormLoad when uploaded, works in preview

Tags: infopath, active-directory, custom-form

Purpose of form is for the filler to enter employee name/account id/etc into people picker. AccountId is pushed to ADS Web Service AccountName, queried, and form is filled with employee's WorkEmail, PreferredName, and Manager. The Manager's AccountId then queries a second webservice for the same information, up several levels.

*Working:*
On FormLoad, current user (evaluator) is queried for PreferredName and WorkEmail. Manager chain works in preview mode.

*Not working:*
Queried user (being evaluated) returns DisplayName, AccountId, and AccountType, but will not query ADS service for further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, an employee's name was entered into a people picker, which populated an employee ID field. The Employee ID field had a rule which set the query value from that, queried a data connection and was done. The Employee name field's default value was set to as the value of name = PreferredName, email field default value as name = WorkEmail, etc, up a chain of supervisors. This works in Preview.

To get it working on both all querying and setting of values was done in one rule attached to the employee ID field. All subsequent fields were left with blank default values.